# how to close a currently opened window not by using "This.Close", but accessing a method of a class

Tags: c#

i am a total beginner to programming .. how to close a currently opened window not by using "This.Close", but accessing a method of a class that is in a class library ? when the close button is clicked , i want it to instantiate the class and then  execute the close method defined in a certain class and then close the windows form .. answers will be appreciated . thank you

Comment: can you put up a sample code for it please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class to manage your windows, for example:

```
using System.Windows;

public
static
class WindowManager
{
    private
    static
    Window CurrentWindow;

    public
    static
    void CloseCurrentWindow ()
    {
        WindowManager.CurrentWindow.Close ();
    }

    public
    static
    void ShowMainWindow ()
    {
        MainWindow Window = new MainWindow ();

                                      Window.Show ();
        WindowManager.CurrentWindow = Window;
    }
}
```

And the you would call it from anywhere: WindowManager.CloseCurrentWindow ();
Be aware that static classes can make your code harder to understand later as your software grows
so there might be alternatives to this problem.

Comment: is there a special reference to be added to make "windowManager work ? i am using visual studio 2010

Comment: It must be inside the namespace of your project, I didn't wrote the namespace so that you can write to envelope the example. I added "using System.Windows" at the top of the file too because of variable CurrentWindow. The MainWindow is just an example of a window called MainWindow inside your project.